# Serial Number Box Wont Autofill Anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, coldfusion-10

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQaHp.png)Last year, Chrome made updates that blocks certain javascript from working properly. I have this working in Internet Explorer but it doesn't work in Firefox, Edge, or Chrome.

When selecting a specific Part, which is checked in pcpSelect variable, the Serial number correlated to that part will automatically display in the text box. But it is getting blocked now and I am having issues getting the DOM to work properly now. Does anyone have any suggestions? [Here is a screenshot of the error after selecting part number from dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMq3s.png)

```js
function fillSerial()
{
    var pcpSelect = document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID.selectedIndex;
    var PCP = document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID(pcpSelect).value;
    //alert(PCP);
    for (var i = 1; i < PCP_array.length; i++) 
    {
        if ( PCP == PCP_array[i] )
            {
            document.frm_CreatePCP.sn.value = Number(Serial_array[i]) +1;
            document.frm_CreatePCP.sn.refresh;
            document.frm_CreatePCP.part.value=PCP;
            //document.getElementById("openserial").onclick="javascript:void window.open('selectExistSerial.cfm?pcp_id='+PCP+','1351625603240','width=300,height=150,resizable=1,left=650,top=300');" ;
            document.getElementById("openserial").disabled = false;
            break;
            
            }
    }
}

function openSerialWindow()
{
    var pcpSelect = document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID.selectedIndex;
    var PCP = document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID(pcpSelect).value;
    if (PCP.length < 1) {
        alert ("Part is required");
        document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID.focus();
        }
    else
    {
    //alert(PCP);
    //mywindow = window.open("'selectExistSerial.cfm?pcp_id='+PCP+','1351625603240','width=300,height=150,resizable=1,left=650,top=300'");
    mywindow = window.open('selectExistSerial.cfm?pcp_id='+PCP,'mywindow','width=650,height=350,resizable=1,left=650,top=300,scrollbars=1');
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="man_insp_enter_serial.cfm" name="frm_CreatePCP" method="post" > <!-- changed name to id name="frm_CreatePCP" -->
    <input type="hidden" name="part" value="<cfoutput>#form.part#</cfoutput>">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="2" align="center" >
        <tr>
            <td align="center"  colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div class="bluem" >Start Manual Inspection Template</div></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"  >
                <b>Part:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
                <select name="PCP_ID" onchange="fillSerial();" >
                    <option value="">Choose One</option>
                    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type="text/javascript">
                        var Serial_array = new Array();
                        var PCP_array = new Array();
                    </SCRIPT>               
                    <cfset j=1>
                    <cfoutput query="qryAporvedPCP">
                        <option value="#qryAporvedPCP.PCP_ID#" <cfif qryAporvedPCP.PCP_ID eq form.part> selected </cfif> >#qryAporvedPCP.PARTNUM#</option>
                        <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type= "text/javascript" >
                            Serial_array[#j#] = "#qryAporvedPCP.MAX_SERIAL#";
                            PCP_array[#j#] = "#qryAporvedPCP.PCP_ID#";
                        </SCRIPT>
                        <cfset j=j+1>
                        <!-- <cfset ary_PCP_ID = ListToArray( valueList(qryAporvedPCP.PCP_ID) ) >
                        <cfset ary_SERIAL = ListToArray( valueList(qryAporvedPCP.MAX_SERIAL) ) > -->
                        </cfoutput>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td >Serial Number: <input type="text" name="sn" size="7" maxlength="7" style="text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; font-weight:bold" onkeypress="return isNumberDecKey(event);" value="" />&nbsp;<input type="button" name="openSerial" value ="S/N Used"  onclick="javascript: openSerialWindow()" ></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="freq" value="0"  />
            <input type="hidden" name="temp" value="68"  />
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `PCP_ID()` do?

Comment: The PCP_ID is an identifier for the part number the user selects so it can tie it to the appropriate serial number we have.

Comment: You should include the function in your post.

Comment: Sorry about that, so PCP_ID is tied directly via a sql key, which we tied to an array called PCP_array. It wasn't defined as a literal function per say, but is used to identify each item in the drop down box. 
 <SCRIPT language=JavaScript type= "text/javascript" >
                                    Serial_array[#j#] = "#qryAporvedPCP.MAX_SERIAL#";
                                    PCP_array[#j#] = "#qryAporvedPCP.PCP_ID#";
                                </SCRIPT>

Comment: I see your ColdFusion-generated script (I've done CF for 13 years), but that still doesn't show what `PCP_ID()` does. It's called in Javascript, and it's function syntax; I don't know what else it could be. At least, what is it returning? Not what it theoretically returns, but what do you get when you actually call it? Because you say this only works in IE, I suspect whatever you are trying to do isn't actually valid JS.

Comment: I test your code and it shows error in all browsers including IE. I get the same error like the one in your screenshot. The error shows the code you get the `<select>` value in `PCP` is wrong. You can edit the code into `document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID[pcpSelect].value`. Then it can get the value correctly and works in all browsers. Besides, your code doesn't autofill the text box in all browsers including IE.

Comment: @Yu Zhou, thank you! Your solution helped me fix the issue. I knew it was something tiny I was missing :D

Comment: @Plumbboy77 I'm glad that you have fixed the issue. I'd like to post it as an answer and you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when my answer helps to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and it shows error in all browsers including IE. I get the same error like the one in your screenshot. The error shows the code you get the `<select>` value in `PCP` is wrong. You can edit the code into `document.frm_CreatePCP.PCP_ID[pcpSelect].value`. Then it can get the value correctly and works in all browsers.